# Externalizing data from an Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to take ownership of the memory backing an `Eigen::Matrix` without copying the memory. The `data()` method retains ownership. The only way I've figured out how to do this is by swapping the mapped array:

```
Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> mat = m1 * m2;
// want ownership of mat's float*

float* data = mat.data(); // get the pointer
new (&mat) Eigen::Map<Matrix3f>(NULL); // swap the mapped array with anything else
// do something with data
```

It doesn't look like this causes a copy under the hood, but I'm not positive. I'm also not sure that this is safe.

Comment: Why not just keep the Eigen matrix object alive while you need its data?

Comment: @rubenvb I need to hand the data off to another environment where I don't have that much control.

Comment: That is a very unclear statement. I still don't see the problem with keeping the Eigen object alive while that other environment does its thing.

Comment: @rubenv sorry -- basically I'm providing an API function that returns a `float *`.

Comment: Then you can provide the contract for how to handle that memory. And that means you can store the Eigen object until a user calls a certain "free" function, at which point you delete the object associated with the pointer. If the user then decides to do something bad, well, there wasn't anything you could have ever done to prevent that. We are talking C(++) here.

Comment: @ZachB A `float*` isn't a full API.  A `float*` allocated *by what means*, and *freed by what means*?  In C/C++ you must always keep track of who owns what, and how to dispose of leftover data.  If you fail, you end up with leaks and corruption and mess.

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic -- This is a binding to another language, which wraps the `float*` and takes ownership of its memory, taking care of freeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tearing memory out of the guts of `Eigen` is impolite, not the least of which because you don't know how it was allocated or what else the Matrix owned.

There is, however, the [`Map` template](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html), which lets you wrap an unowned buffer into a Eigen-matrix-like type.

This type isn't an actual eigen matrix, so your own custom functions may not work with it, but it should work with Eigen functions.

In this case, you already own the data.

```
using matrix_type = Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>;
using mapped_matrix_type = Map<matrix_type>;
```

Now we create a buffer, wrap it in a `mapped_matrix_type`, and assign:

```
auto raw = std::make_unique<float[]>(m1.rows()*m2.cols()); // maybe backwards
mapped_matrix_type bob(raw.get(), m1.rows(), m2.cols());
bob = m1*m2;
```

the raw data of the `bob` is in `raw`, a `unique_ptr` owned buffer (which can `release()` if you need to to make it totally unowned).

Any raw storage mechanism (`vector`, raw `new`, whatever else) can take the place of `raw`.

Code not tested.